# How to check for null attributes in LinqToXML expressions?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I have a LinqToXML expression where I am trying to select distinct names based on similar attributes.  The code is working great and I've put it below:

```
            var q = xmlDoc.Element("AscentCaptureSetup").Element("FieldTypes")
            .Descendants("FieldType")
            .Select(c => new { width = c.Attribute("Width").Value,
                                script = c.Attribute("ScriptName").Value,
                                sqlType = c.Attribute("SqlType").Value,
                                enableValues = c.Attribute("EnableValues").Value,
                                scale = c.Attribute("Scale").Value,
                                forceMatch = c.Attribute("ForceMatch").Value,
                                forceMatchCaseSensitive = c.Attribute("ForceMatchCaseSensitive").Value,
                                sortAlphabetically = c.Attribute("SortAlphabetically").Value,
                            })
            .Distinct();
```

The problem arises since not all the attributes are required, and if one of them is omitted, for example *sortAlphabetically*, I get an Object not Referenced error.  Makes sense, but it there a way to alter the query to only use assign the new values if the attribute actually exists? (Thereby bypassing any null pointer errors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the `Value` property (which will blow up on a null reference), simply cast the `XAttribute` to string - you'll *either* get the value, *or* a null reference if the `XAttribute` reference is null. (`XElement` works the same way, and this applies to all conversions to nullable types.)

So you'd have:

```
.Select(c => new { 
     width = (string) c.Attribute("Width"),
     script = (string) c.Attribute("ScriptName"),
     sqlType = (string) c.Attribute("SqlType"),
     enableValues = (string) c.Attribute("EnableValues"),
     scale = (string) c.Attribute("Scale"),
     forceMatch = (string) c.Attribute("ForceMatch"),
     forceMatchCaseSensitive = (string) c.Attribute("ForceMatchCaseSensitive"),
     sortAlphabetically = (string) c.Attribute("SortAlphabetically"),
 })
```

Some of those attributes sound like they should *actually* be cast to `int?` or `bool?`, mind you...

Comment: Doh!  You've had your coffee and I didn't.  Good catch on the cast, will work great.  As far and the casting types shouldn't matter, those variables will only be used to create log output.  Thanks Jon